# Swift: parsing dynamic JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to parse this JSON that has a changing key for each object Im trying to find the best way to parse each object. I am very new to swift programming so any example code would be very helpful.  I don't need to store all the values received just particular field such as address, streetName, image

### JSON Input

```
{ 
"a000!%5362657": {

    "address": "20 Ingram Street",
    "streetName": "Ingram Street",
    "streetNumber": "20",
    "streetDirection": "N",
    "unitNumber": "",
    "cityName": "Forest Hills",
    "countyName": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "zipcode": "11375",
    "listingPrice": "$1,151,000",
    "listingID": "5362657",
    "remarksConcat": "From nytimes.com: In the comics, Peter Parker, the mild-mannered photojournalist who is Spider-Man's alter ego, grew up at 20 Ingram Street, a modest, two-story boarding house run by his Aunt May in the heart of Forest Hills Gardens. The address actually exists and is home to a family named Parker: Andrew and Suzanne Parker, who moved there in 1974, and their two daughters. In 1989, the family began receiving junk mail addressed to Peter Parker. We got tons of it, Mrs. Parker said yesterday. Star Trek magazines, a Discover Card in his name, and notices from them over the years calling him a good customer. There were also prank phone calls, all of which she attributed to a teenager who found it funny that we had the same last name as Spider-Man.",
    "rntLse": "neither",
    "propStatus": "Active",
    "bedrooms": "3",
    "totalBaths": "2.75",
    "latitude": "40.712968",
    "longitude": "-73.843206",
    "acres": "0.24",
    "sqFt": "2,760",
    "displayAddress": "y",
    "listingAgentID": "8675301",
    "listingOfficeID": "lmnop",
    "sample_mlsPtID": "1",
    "sample_mlsPhotoCount": "39",
    "parentPtID": "1",
    "detailsURL": "a000/5362657",
    "idxID": "a000",
    "idxPropType": "Residential",
    "idxStatus": "active",
    "viewCount": "2",
    "mediaData": [],
    "ohCount": "0",
    "vtCount": "0",
    "featured": "n",
    "image": {
        "0": {
            "url": "http://cdn.photos.ample_mls.com/az/20151113223546806109000000.jpg",
            "caption": "17596-20"
        },
        "totalCount": "39"
    },
    "fullDetailsURL": "http://sample_return.idxbroker.com/idx/details/listing/a000/5362657/20-Ingram-Street-Forrest-Hills-NY-11375"
},
"a000!%5358959": {
    "address": "177A Bleecker Street",
    "streetName": "Bleecker Street",
    "streetNumber": "177",
    "streetDirection": "N",
    "unitNumber": "A",
    "cityName": "Greenwich Village",
    "countyName": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "zipcode": "10012",
    "listingPrice": "$616,000,000",
    "listingID": "5358959",
    "remarksConcat": "Home to Dr. Stephen Vincent Strange(Doctor Strange in Marvel comics) and his faithful bodyguard and manservant Wong. Spider-Man often visits the Doctor for help when battling those with magic powers. Features: Wong's Storage Cellar, Strange's bedchambers, guest quarters, Wong's bedchamber, Study, Meditain Chamber, Library, Storage Area for Occult Artifacts.",
    "rntLse": "neither",
    "propStatus": "Active",
    "bedrooms": "2",
    "totalBaths": "2.75",
    "latitude": "40.729117",
    "longitude": "-74.000773",
    "acres": "0.31",
    "sqFt": "206800000000",
    "displayAddress": "y",
    "listingAgentID": "8675301",
    "listingOfficeID": "lmnop",
    "sample_mlsPtID": "1",
    "sample_mlsPhotoCount": "34",
    "parentPtID": "1",
    "detailsURL": "a000/5358959",
    "idxID": "a000",
    "idxPropType": "Residential",
    "idxStatus": "active",
    "viewCount": "6",
    "mediaData": [],
    "ohCount": "0",
    "vtCount": "0",
    "featured": "y",
    "image": {
        "0": {
            "url": "http://cdn.photos.sample_mls.com/az/20151105214013253867000000.jpg",
            "caption": "Front"
        },
        "totalCount": "34"
    },
    "fullDetailsURL": "http://sample_return.idxbroker.com/idx/details/listing/a000/5358959/177A-Bleecker-Street-Greenwich-Village-NY-10012"
}
}
```

---

### swift viewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

//final let urlString = "http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors"
final let urlString = "https://api.idxbroker.com/clients/featured"

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var nameArray = [String]()
var dobArray = [String]()
var imgURLArray = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.downloadJsonWithTask()
    //self.downloadJsonWithURL()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/***********************************************************************************************/

func downloadJsonWithTask() {

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    var downloadTask = URLRequest(url: (url as URL?)!, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 20)


/************** Get Users Accesy Key for API CALL *************************/
    var key = String()
    let textFieldKeyConstant = "AccessKey"

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let textFieldValue = defaults.string(forKey: textFieldKeyConstant) {
        key = textFieldValue
    }

    print(key) //accesskey debug
/******************** End Get accessKey *************************************/

/******************** Add Headers required for API CALL *************************************/
    downloadTask.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    downloadTask.setValue(key, forHTTPHeaderField: "accesskey")
    downloadTask.setValue("json", forHTTPHeaderField: "outputtype")

    downloadTask.httpMethod = "GET"
    /******************** End Headers required for API CALL *************************************/


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadTask, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)


print(jsonData ?? "Default")

/******** Parse JSON **********/



/******** End Parse JSON **********/


/******** Reload table View **********/
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })        }).resume()
}
    /***********************************************************************************************/
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nameArray.count
}
/***********************************************************************************************/
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.dobLabel.text = dobArray[indexPath.row]

    let imgURL = NSURL(string: imgURLArray[indexPath.row])

    if imgURL != nil {
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imgURL as URL?)!)
        cell.imgView.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
    }

    return cell
}
/****************************************************************/

///for showing next detailed screen with the downloaded info
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController
    vc.imageString = imgURLArray[indexPath.row]
    vc.nameString = nameArray[indexPath.row]
    vc.dobString = dobArray[indexPath.row]

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}


}
```

Comment: `try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]` will convert it to a `Dictionary` with `String` keys that you can loop over.

Comment: some nodes about coding style: make a struct (`DataModel`) for the things you get from jscon and put this in an array. and extract the json download in a different network layer class to remove network retrieving logic from your tableview logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for swift3  `[String:Any]` it is  a **Dictionary** with key has **String** and  **Any** type in Swift, which describes a value of any type

```
 do {
      let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
        print(parsedData)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
```

For example :

```
if  let info = parsedData["a000!%5362657"] as? [String : String]{
    if let address = info["address"]  {
        print(address)
    }
}
```

Working with JSON in Swift   apple blog https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Comment: "a000!%5362657" is a dynamic key (meaning it changes) could you show me a way to parse the data without knowing that key i.e. generic

Comment: Could you trying with 'enumerated' for get key , value from parsedData . Ex. for (key , value) in parsedData.enumerated() { print(key) print(value)

Comment: You can try a solution from this article [link](https://swiftsenpai.com/swift/decode-dynamic-keys-json)